# Can't access file I created in Android app on PC

Tags: java, android

I wrote some app that writes some data in external memory on SD card (actually I don't have SD card, but path is /sdcard/map/file. When I check file on my phone with ES File explorer I can see and open file, but I can't see this file on PC. Anybody know what could be problem?

```
private void createMapFile(String fileName, byte mapBytes[]) throws IOException {       
            File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/map/"+ fileName);

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
            os.write(mapBytes);
            os.close();
        }
```

This is the method I'm using for writing binary arrays of data into file.

Comment: How are you writing the file? Post the code. The path `/sdcard/map/` may not be the mount point for USB mass storage.

Comment: I posted method for writing data to file.

Comment: Yeap, the path looks OK.

Comment: You mean you cannot see the file in your emulator ?

Comment: No, I have connected phone over USB on PC, and when I browse files on phone, "map" is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got to be on MTP, right? If you are browsing the SD card immediately after writing the file, the MTP interface may not show the changes. Try

- Disconnect/reconnect your phone
- Reboot the phone/PC

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
File myFile;
...
// myFile creates somewhere here
...
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{myFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

After that, you will instantly can see created file on connected PC.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the default file creation permissions of your Android app not being compatible with the user permissions of your PC...this is a known problem with Android and it not easily solved.

If your Android device is rooted, you can change the permissions on the file through the use of the "chmod" linux terminal command to make the file globally visible instead of only being visible to it's creator.  That will enable your PC to see the file.

If your device is not rooted, then you will probably have to use a cloud service such as Dropbox or Google Drive to move the file to the cloud, which then can be accessed by your PC.

Comment: In addition to this question already having an accurate answer, there are two problems with your suggestion.  First, there is no concept of owner-only access permission for the traditional External Storage mentioned in the question.  Second, there are several alternatives to cloud services: first, using the external storage as this question does rather than the private storage.  Second, with the private storage even on a non-rooted device, the owner of the file (typically the app which created it) has the ability to set the mode bits to allow everyone access.